# IBMi STRSEU - Possible to edit stream files (IFS) directly?

Tags: git, ibm-midrange, rpgle, ibm-ifs

On an IBMi system, STRSEU can only work with source members, right? No ability to interact with stream files directly.

Just thinking in the context of tracking RPG/CL/DDS source behind Git as stream files.

Assuming one wanted to use STRSEU, I can only think of this process while still tracking changes behind Git:

```
Open up member in SEU
Make changes, save, compile, test.
CPYTOSTMF to IFS file in tracked Git directory
Commit change and other Git things.
Proceed to push live...
```

Given that SEU hasn't been supported for years at this point, I'm fairly skeptical that editing stream files directly is possible. But am really just checking there isn't some workaround (besides the above) I'm unaware of.

Comment: Assuming one wanted to use a hammer to drive screws, you would jut get a bigger hammer. But the real solution is to avoid using a tool for something it was not designed to do.

Comment: Given that SEU hasn't been supported in years, why would you want to use it?

Comment: You're preaching to the choir, I'm trying to "support" others. I finally got buy in to put our source behind Git, but that requires using stream files rather than source members. I won't be able to sell RDI to them, so I'm hoping to get them to use VS Code. But if I can't, I want to have a complete picture of what's possible.

Comment: VS Code should operate directly on stream files. Or use Notepad++ that will operate directly on stream files as well.

Comment: For sure, Ideally I can convince them to use VSCode. Though I'm not too confident. I'm concerned they're going to say to forget Git, simply because they don't want to stop using SEU.

Comment: Start using VS Code and Git, and start writing programs using modern RPGIV in **free format. They will have to turn off error checking in SEU, and it will become useless to them.

Comment: Yeah, they've already turned off error checking in SEU and use a good amount of free format. They still would rather use SEU over rational.  But you're preaching to the choir, I think RDi is a horrible IDE, and it's still light years better than SEU. As soon as/if we switch to stream files and Git, you can bet your buttons I'm using VS Code. And I can't use stream files now because it wipes out the date columns on the source members. And that is the "version control" currently in place.

Comment: There are cheaper products, but I like RDi. I guess it's what you are used to. RDi doesn't interface to Git well though.

Comment: It is not correct that stream files have to lose the dates. See the [docs](https://halcyon-tech.github.io/vscode-ibmi/#/?id=enable-source-dates) and a [screenshot](https://contattafiles.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ibmioss/wVwQ15j93tIG1xJ/Pasted%20Image%3A%20Mar%203%2C%202022%20-%203%3A43%3A34pm).

Comment: Oh this is awesome, I didn't realize there was an option to preserve dates when using Code for IBMi.  I must have missed it when I tried it out. Thanks for this @JohnY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
From the command line

```
cd '/tmp'
wrklnk
```

[image]
When you see the file you want to edit listed, edit it with option 2

[image]

You gonna need to learn the basic options valid on this editor, press F1 for help.

Comment: Thanks, it's not SEU, but it's the closest option available for editing stream files from 5250 screens.

Comment: Now that you can compile programs using IFS files, you can store and edit programs directly in IFS. You can even use RDi to edit this files and compile from there or from green screen! :)

Comment: Just to be clear, the editor here is EDTF, which is mentioned in the [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71443986/95852).

Answer (score 4):

SEU can't work with stream files.

Use the `EDTF` command to edit stream files.

Answer (score 0):

RDi is the replacement for SEU, and can edit stream files. Many of the other GUI editors can be used to edit stream files as well.